# How to wait for two conditions in a Sharepoint Designer 2010 Workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a workflow in SPD10 and I want to tell the workflow to wait for two different conditions. So the workflow does the same thing after wait for either the first or the second condition.

How can i do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any similarity between the two fields? You can use the operator does not contain, contains, etc to get your field to equal a certain value. Can you list the field and possible values, or otherwise what you are dealing with?

Comment: The field is "status", and it could be either rejected or ceo review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this. Making the condition of the wait action to "match a regular expression". Yes, a RegEx. For example:

```
wait for "status" to match regular expresion "Rejected|CEO Review"
```

Hope this help someone else out there! :)